# Set values to text identifier by var name. An alternative to getIdentifier

Tags: android, identifier, android-xml

I am trying to set String values for ids defined in xmls. I have defined the set of text which can be assigned to different ids in the layout xml files. Thereby I can also see the int values that are associated with different texts in R.java.

I have stored the variable names that I have given to the texts in my database along with the R.id prefix as they appear in R.java file.
For setting text,

```
TextView messageone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
```

**Normal Usage:**

```
String message = "Hi, hello";
messageone.setText(Status);
```

**What i want to implement:**

- public static final int messagestring is present in R.java
- R.id.messagestring is stored in sqlite database in text format
  messageone.setText(what_here);
- what_here = a way to get the value from "R.id.messagestring" string as obtained from database.

I know `public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)`
can be used here. The only change would be stored text in database will change from `R.id.messagestring` to `messagestring`. But there is a note discouraging this type of implementation.

It says: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name. 
[Android Docs getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

I think although this method seems like a longer implementation, can be efficient when the objects dealt with are not text.

Answer (score 0):

There's a getString(int Id) method you can use inside an Activity. It will return a String from a given R.string Id.

String something = getString(R.string.something);

I hope I helped out a bit here, because I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question.

Comment: What i want (considering ur eg) is R.string.something is stored in database as text & i want to replace text with variable. Implementation will be somewhat similar to Class.forname(R.string.something) but with return of primitive int type or a way to convert object to int.